# How to get error message from Job Queue Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

i create a job and queued the job use Bus,
inside the job i throw error message use `$this->fail('error message')` when condition not match
how to get the error message, currently i use `Bus::findBatch($batchId)` but no error message found

i expected way to get error message from jobe

Comment: You can set try/catch block in handle method of job class with logger in catch block.